# Inserting current date into confluence hyperlink

Tags: macros, confluence

I am using this code to display current date in the confluence page.

```
{run-now:dateFormat =d-MMM-yyyy}
$current_time
{run-now}
```

My purpose, to include this date into email hyperlink, like below

```
[Click me|mailto: some_email@domen.com &subject=Update as of - {run-now:dateFormat =d-MMM-yyyy} $current_time{run-now}]
```

My expectations, is that it will show mailto link after clicking which, it will open email with subject that is including current date.

But this is working unexpectedly

it shows me something like this instead of the link

```
 function run_moreDisplayToggle_1() { // toggle display of "more" rows of parameter table on or of //alert("test"); var table = document.getElementById("run_table_1"); var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr"); var isMoreFound = false; for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { var row = rows.item(i); if (row.id.match("1_row_")) { if (row.style.display == "none") { row.style.display = ""; isMoreFound = true; } else { row.style.display = "none"; } } } var icon = document.getElementById("run_1_advanced_toggle"); var moreElement = document.getElementById("run_1__more") if (isMoreFound) { icon.src = "/images/icons/subtract_12.gif"; icon.title = "Less"; moreElement.value = "true"; } else { icon.src = "/images/icons/add_12.gif"; icon.title = "More"; moreElement.value = "false"; } }
29-Jan-2014" class="external-link" rel="nofollow">Click me
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better you use [HTML Macro](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/HTML+Macro) to hyperlink your email.

I think it should be something like this:

```
{html}<a mailto: some_email@domen.com &subject=Update as of - {run-now:dateFormat =d-MMM-yyyy} $current_time{run-now}/a>{html}
```

Anyway as the confluence expertise always online in [Answers](http://answers.atlassian.com) I recommend you to check there.

Comment: This is definitely the easiest way imho